# Firstrun "How it works" #herobox is misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I like to think the Ask Ubuntu is lawful good but we've got a box on the homepage that is clearly chaotic evil. What, no AD&D fans in tonight?       **sighs**       Tough crowd.

Awful jokes aside, the `#herobox` element is skwiffy.

[image]

#### EDIT

Oh, you mean this #herobox, my bad ;)

[image]

Comment: Eeeh, I have no idea what you just said...

Comment: What? Why is it called a "herobox"? And why is there a problem with it?

Comment: Ah... It's misaligned, sorry, didn't read all of your question...

Comment: I'm not sure what you *did* read, it's in the title, the question and the screenshot :)

Comment: Same here, Chromium 48.0.2564.116 64-bit.

Comment: I guess this is due to the sidebar change - it's exactly 60px too wide.

Answer (score 2):

The hero box width is now correct and should no longer overflow.